# Resource recommendation for symmetries in condensed matter physics

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, symmetry

Could you kindly tell me where I could find the rudiments and simple applications of symmetries like particle-hole, chiral etc. in the context of condensed matter physics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of my favorite resources on the subject of symmetries in condensed matter physics:

1. [Fradkin's Field Theories of Condensed Matter Physics](https://books.google.com/books?id=x7_6MX4ye_wC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false): Discussions of symmetry scattered throughout the chapters. Good, comprehensive discussion, though it has a small bias to topological states of matter.
2. [Xiao-Gang Wen's Quantum Field Theory of Many-Body Systems](https://books.google.com/books?id=RYESDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Xiao%20gang%20wen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLnO20vtTUAhUIcj4KHSVWBoMQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=Xiao%20gang%20wen&f=false): Clear emphasis on topological states of matter. A little advanced.
3. El-Batanouny and Frederick Wooten's [Symmetry and Condensed Matter Physics, A Computational Approach](https://books.google.com/books?id=RxLnDK8Mj5AC&printsec=frontcover&dq=symmetry%20and%20condensed%20matter&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOnsTgvtTUAhVKPD4KHeGHDnwQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=symmetry%20and%20condensed%20matter&f=false): A pedagogical introduction to the nitty gritty of symmetry in condensed matter physics. Discussions on group theory, space groups, tensor fields, phase transitions, and quasi-crystals. Good introduction to the mathematics of symmetry.

Also see [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251072/symmetries-in-physics-specifically-condensed-matter-physics) and [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86293/what-is-the-definition-of-particle-hole-symmetry-in-condensed-matter-physics?rq=1) on Physics StackExchange for discussions on chiral and particle-hole symmetry.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a resource where all these would be in one place since it seemed that everything was quite scattered.
Does Wooten's book discuss symmetries like chiral/particle-hole too or just symmetries of crystals?

Comment: I'm looking at it now, and it seems to be mostly crystalline. Fradkin's book mentions particle-hole symmetry on p. 14, and chiral symmetry on pages 108, 111, and 453, so perhaps that would be a better reference for you.